# Comparing values in multiple columns in R dataframes & updating missing values

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 3 dataframes . 
first df contains one column - Name -

```
df 1
    Name 
    A    
    B    
    C    
    D    
    E    
    F    
    G  
    H
    I
    J
    K
```

Second df contains two columns - Name and counts but some of the Names may or may not be missing from first df.

```
df 2 - 
  Name   Counts 
    A    12
    B    23
    C    34
    D    56
    E    34
    K    44
```

I want compare all Names from second df to first df , If none of the names are missing , then fine. 
If any name is missing then that name and its count has to be filled from third df . The third df will always have names and counts available in it.

```
df 3 - 
 Name   Counts 
    A    34
    B    45
    C    34
    D    56
    E    67
    F    435
    G    45
    H    76
    I    76
    J    88
    K    90
```

So in above example Since F, G, H , I, J are missing in second df , their info should be added from df 3 .

and 
second df should be updated as -

```
Name   Counts 
    A    12
    B    23
    C    34
    D    56
    E    34
    F    435
    G    45
    H    76
    I    76
    J    88
    K    44
```

Any help here would be great

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do...

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF1); setDT(DF2); setDT(DF3)

DF1[, n := unique(rbind(DF2, DF3), by="Name")[.(.SD$Name), on=.(Name), x.Counts]]
```

which adds a column to DF1:

```
    Name   n
 1:    A  12
 2:    B  23
 3:    C  34
 4:    D  56
 5:    E  34
 6:    F 435
 7:    G  45
 8:    H  76
 9:    I  76
10:    J  88
11:    K  44
```

You could instead do `merge(DF1, unique(rbind(DF2, DF3), by="Name"), all.x=TRUE)`, though that would create a new table instead of adding a column to an existing table. The dplyr analogue of this merge is `left_join(DF1, bind_rows(DF2, DF3) %>% distinct(Name))`.

*How it works*

- `DF = rbind(DF2, DF3)` appends the two source tables
- `uDF = unique(DF, by="Name")` keeps the first row for each `Name`
- `DF1[, n := z]` adds column `n` with values `z` to `DF1`
- `z = x[i, on=, x.v]` uses `i` to look up rows of `x` then returns column `v`, where...

  - `x = uDF`
  - `v = Counts`
  - `i = .SD$Name` is the vector of names found in `DF1`

`.SD` in `j` of `DT[i, j]` refers to `DT` itself, the "Subset of Data".

Comment: I tried to do this in base R, but couldn't find a clean way. Looks like my initial edit with that attempt got eaten by the five-minute window...

Comment: Thanks , In the first code - I got error - Error in `[.data.table`(unique(rbind(df2, df3), by = "Name"), .SD$Name,  : 
  logical error. i is not a data.table, but 'on' argument is provided. The second method of merging is working but since its doing Union how can i get rid of duplicate rows in that case ? Thanks

Comment: Hm, I made an edit to wrap `.SD$Name` inside `.(...)` which might fix the error. I am not sure I understand what you mean by union or duplicate rows. Is it possible that there could be duplicate rows within DF2 or within DF3?