# Replacing NA values from another dataframe by id

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe df1 as below -

```
ID Count 
11  345
22  456
33  786
44  765
55  NA
66  888
77  NA
```

Then i have a df2 as below -

```
 ID  Count 
 11  536
 22  654
 33  786
 44  999
 55  890
 66  111
 77  654
```

I want `NA` values in `df1` to be replaced by values from `df2` for those specific id.

The resulting `df3` should be:

```
ID  Count 
11  345
22  456
33  786
44  765
55  890
66  888
77  654
```

Any help will be great 
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Use of `dplyr::coalesce` will make task simpler.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% inner_join(df2, by= "ID") %>%
  mutate(Count = coalesce(Count.x, Count.y)) %>%
  select(ID, Count)

#   ID Count
# 1 11   345
# 2 22   456
# 3 33   786
# 4 44   765
# 5 55   890
# 6 66   888
# 7 77   654
```

**Data:**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = 
"ID Count 
11  345
22  456
33  786
44  765
55  NA
66  888
77  NA",
header = TRUE)

df2 <- read.table(text = 
"ID  Count 
11  536
22  654
33  786
44  999
55  890
66  111
77  654",
header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an update join to edit those rows in the first table:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF1); setDT(DF2)

DF1[is.na(Count), Count := DF2[.SD, on=.(ID), x.Count]]
```

*How it works*

- `DF[i, j]` filters by `i` then does `j`
- So in `j`, `.SD` refers to the subset of data after filtering with `i`
- A `j` with `:=` adds or modifies columns in the table
- `x[i, on=, x.v]` is [as described in this similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49984344/)

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, by = c("ID")) %>%
  mutate(Count = ifelse(is.na(Count.x), Count.y, Count.x)) %>%
  select(-c(Count.x, Count.y))
```

This yields

```
  ID Count
1 11   345
2 22   456
3 33   786
4 44   765
5 55   890
6 66   888
7 77   654
```